# Passar o android studio para outro computador sem precisar instalar

Tags: java, android-studio, instalador

To de férias em uma cidade pequena, aqui a internet é muito lenta, quero passar o android studio para um computador mais avançado que comprei, só que não consigo via internet, queria saber se é possível eu passar o android da outro computador para este mais novo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como não existe uma versão portable, o mais concreto a se fazer (dependendo do SO) é buscar a pasta onde foi instalado e copiar.

Answer (score 0):

Se o seu computador for Windows, isso não será possivel. Apenas baixando o instalador mesmo você vai conseguir isso.

Já se for Linux ou OS X, você pode copiar a pasta onde o Studio fica instalado. Por que nesse caso o android não "instala" realmente, ele só move os arquivos para o diretório dos programas e cria um atalho.

No Linux, geralmente o Android Studio fica instalado por padrão dentro da pasta /opt. Já no OSx vá no finder, encontre o atalho do AndroidStudio, clique com dois dedos sobre e selecione "Mostrar conteúdo do Pacote" copie a pasta contents.

Mas nada vai adiantar se a outra máquina não tiver o java instalado ou for de sistemas operacionais diferentes.

Boa sorte!